# Saving terminals within Webstorm

Tags: webstorm

I use the terminal plugin within Webstorm 9 to run local services with programming.

Does anyone know of a way to re-open created terminals when a project is opened?

As an example, let's say I close the project with three terminals open.  I would want to see those same terminals tabs in the list when I re-open the project.

Comment: have you got a way to do this yet ?

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557036/how-to-save-and-restore-terminal-sessions-for-a-specific-intellij-project) it looks like it's on the JetBrains horizon but hasn't been started yet. Here are the JetBrains ticket references taken from that answer on SO: [ticket 1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117946), [ticket 2](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134884)